# Group Concatenate in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, concatenation, group-concat

I have two tables dbo.Supplier and dbo.L_ProductSupplier (AS LPST) and for all product IDs on LPST table, I want to concatenate the Supplier Names from dbo.Supplier (AS ST) which is linked to LPST by the SupplierID field (each product can have multiple suppliers)

e.g. the query should take this:

```
LPST.ProductID  LPST.SupplierID ST.SupplierName
1                          A    CompanyA
1                          B    CompanyB
1                          C    CompanyC
2                          X    CompanyX
2                          Y    CompanyY
2                          Z    CompanyZ
```

And output this:

```
LPST.ProductID  SupplierName(s)
1               CompanyA / CompanyB /CompanyC
2               CompanyX / CompanyY / CompanyZ
```

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
LPST.ProductId,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + ST.SupplierName
FROM dbo.Supplier AS ST
WHERE LPST.SupplierId=ST.SupplierId
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS SupplierNames 
FROM dbo.L_ProductSupplier AS LPST
GROUP BY LPST.ProductId
```

...but it gives the error: Column 'dbo.L_ProductSupplier.SupplierId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Any ideas on how I can resolve this? If I remove the "Group By" then it reports each line on LPST without concatenation.

Is there another way of doing it? I hear that cursors are an option but I'm new to SQL and aren't familiar with them; does anybody have experience with cursors in this instance?

Comment: Theres several ways of doing this - none of them particularly elegant. See [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) for a complete list of your options. I'd probably go with the `FOR XML PATH` option (as per answer by KumarHarsh) as its the most succinct

Comment: Thanks James, the FOR XML PATH was the route I had gone down but my code didn't do the desired results, any ideas where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DECLARE @Supplier TABLE(
    SupplierId INT,
    SupplierName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Supplier SELECT 1, 'A'
INSERT INTO @Supplier SELECT 2, 'B'

DECLARE @L_ProductSupplier TABLE(
    ProductId INT,
    SupplierId INT
)       

INSERT INTO @L_ProductSupplier SELECT 1, 1
INSERT INTO @L_ProductSupplier SELECT 1, 2


;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  LPST.ProductId,
                LPST.SupplierId,
                ST.SupplierName
        FROM    @L_ProductSupplier LPST LEFT JOIN
                @Supplier ST ON LPST.SupplierId = st.SupplierId
)
SELECT  LPST.ProductId,
        STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT ',' + ST.SupplierName
                    FROM Vals AS ST
                    WHERE LPST.ProductId=ST.ProductId
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ),
                1,
                1,
                ''
            ) AS SupplierNames 
FROM    Vals AS LPST
GROUP BY    LPST.ProductId
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/29960)

Comment: thanks astander, would this work if there were say 200 company names and I didn't know which ones corresponded to which products?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @t table (ProductID int,  SupplierID varchar(1),SupplierName varchar(50))
insert into @t
select 1 ,                         'A'  ,  'CompanyA' union all
select 1                          , 'B'   , 'CompanyB' union all
select 1                         , 'C'   , 'CompanyC' union all
select 2                         , 'X'   , 'CompanyX' union all
select 2                         , 'Y'   , 'CompanyY' union all
select 2                         , 'Z'   , 'CompanyZ'

select distinct b.ProductID,stuff((select '/'+a.SupplierName from @t a where a.ProductID=b.ProductID FOR XML path('')),1,1,'')
from @t b
```

Comment: thanks KumarHarsh... ABCXYZ was just for demonstration purposes, what if there are say 200 company names and I don't know what they all are?

Comment: @user3309874,it really do not matter as far as you want to concatenate suppliername base on productid.you must provide real scenerio data.200 company name do not matter.tell me for which sample data it won't work